# Android Studio load but doesn't display

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded and installed Android Studio but after the loading nothing happens (without any error message), the IDE doesn't display. Am I the only one that had this problem? How can I make it work?

EDIT: 
SO: Windows 7 professional
Android Studio version: 2.3

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @thijs Windows 7 professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through following steps to verify everything is setup to run android studio:

1. Java path settings http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java
2. JDK version Java Development Kit (JDK) 7 or higher
3. Disk space  500 MB disk space
4. Space for Android SDK (At least 1 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
5. Minimum RAM 3 GB, 4 GB RAM recommended
6. Make sure you have installed compatible android studio version (32bit OR 64bit)

**NOTE: Don't forget to restart system after installation**

Comment: Please share your System OS details, android studio version which is installed and screenshot of android studio.

Comment: No screenshot of android studio because it doesn't display.

Comment: Either android studio is incompatible with OS version or it is not properly installed.

Answer (score 1):

No way to make it work, but Android Studio 2.0 work perfectly...